# How to load a gif image with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gif

I want to show a gif image, if the following button was pressed (this is a submit button from the Struts 2 library):

```
<s:submit value="show" onclick="createLoadingLabel()" onblur="deleteLoadingLabel()" />
```

The following Javascript method shows me a gif image, that will not be animated and if I click somewhere on my webpage (the image is static), the gif image will disappear completely from the display:

```
function createLoadingLabel(){

    $('#myDomObject').html('<div id="loadingDiv"><h1>One moment please ...</h1><p align="center"><input style="border:0px" type="image" src="/images/myGifImage.gif" title="loading..."/></p></div>');
 }
```

This is the HTML code, which should be filled by the Javascript function createLoadingLabel():

```
<div>
    <span id="myDomObject"></span>
</div>
```

This is the Javascript function, which will delete the image from display, if the serverside processing will be finished:

```
function (){
    $('#myDomObject').empty();
}
```

How I can make sure, that the gif image will be animated, if the user clicks on the submit button? And is it possible, to position the gif image in the foreground, even if the user clicks somewhere on the webpage?

// Edit

I have written the following Ajax code, which will be executed, if the submit button was pressed, but the gif image isn´t animated and won´t dissapeared, after server side processing is finished:

```
function createLoadingLabel(){

   $('#myDomObject').html('<div id="loadingDiv"><h1>One moment please ...</h1><p align="center"><input style="border:0px" type="image" src="/images/myGifImage.gif" title="loading..."/></p></div>');                   

            $.post("myStrutsActionClass.action", 
                        {firstParam:selectedValue1, secondParam:selectedValue2}, 
                        function(data) {                        
                            $('#myDomObject').empty();
                        });   
}
```

This method is registered in the following way:

```
<s:submit value="show" onclick="createLoadingLabel(); return false" />
```

Comment: check this solution http://jsfiddle.net/VpDUG/4952/

Comment: you need to stop the form submitting otherwise your page will reload before the gif is shown, change your onclick to: `onclick="createLoadingLabel(); return false"`

Comment: You should call [**Ling**](http://www.lingscars.com/), he knows everything about animated gifs

Comment: Use onsubmit on the form element and return false inside.

Comment: @adeneo Thx, you made my day...

Comment: @Pete: Your code make sure, that the gif image will be animated, but teh server side processing won´t be executed !

Comment: Yep, you would have to do that with ajax - that's the only way to get a loading gif to show and then once the call has completed - that's when you remove the loading gif (not onblur of the submit button)

Comment: @Marwief Problem is that while submiting, the UI freeze, so ya use ajax to submit data and in success, you could refresh/redirect depending `form` action attribute

Comment: You contradict yourself: "gif image, that will be not animated" vs "the gif image will be animated" I don't even understand what you mean on animated. Is the gif itself animated, or do you want it to appear/disappear in a slow animation instead of popping up immediately?

Comment: The gif images is animated itselfs. I want to appear it, if the button was pressed and want to disappear it, if the server side processing code was executed. Now the problem is, that the gif image appears, if the button was pressed, but isn´t animated

Comment: GIFs animate in browser, as long as the browser is not doing a synchronous ajax call, during that time they are freezed. `$.post` is asynchronous, so probably this is not the case, but still what would happen if the ajax call is commented temporarily?

Comment: If the ajax call is commented temporarily, the gif image is animated, but the server side code won´t be executed !